# Mouse personalization program with layers

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, mouse, kde, personalization

In Windows there is a program called X-Mouse-Button-Control. 
With it, you can remap the mouse buttons to perform personalized actions including creating a whole new layer, so you can press 2 buttons to perform an action.
But recently I've installed Ubuntu, and I didn't found any alternative for it.

I want a program that allows me to do it.
To be more clear, this is what I used to do in Windows:

- 5th Button = Mute
- 4th Button = Activate Layer 2
- 4th Button + Left Click = Next Music
- 4th Button + Right Click = Previous Music
- 4th Button + Middle Click = Pause/Unpause
- 4th Button + Scroll Up = Volume +
- 4th Button + Scroll Down = Volume -

And for Linux, I would like to add those shortcuts:

- 4th Button + 5th Button = Activate Layer 3
- 4th Button + 5th Button + Left Click = Next Workspace
- 4th Button + 5th Button + Right Click = Previous Workspace